# Python module not found <project> only on VPS. works fine on local machine

Tags: python

**env**

- VPS : ubuntu 16.04
- Python 3.5
- Local: Mac

**project structure**

- inkedNewsCrawler

  - .git /
  - inkedNewsCrawler / (all directory down from here includes "_ *init* _.py")

    - _ *init* _.py
    - custom_crawler /
    - spiders /
    - utils /
    - ect....
  - readme.md
  - requirements.txt

---

Here is how to reproduce.

- Work on local machine,
- push via git.
- Pull from server set up VENV (including pip install..).
- run the script (`>> from inkedNewsCrawler.custom_crawler import x`).

Works fine on local machine but will raise

> ImportError: No module named 'inkedNewsCrawler'

**BUT when i change as `from custom_crawler import x`**

**ON LOCAL**

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'custom_crawler'

**ON VPS**

> Works Fine!!! ???

---

**Things I've tried**

1. added project root to PYTHONPATH
2. triple checked pip, venv settings
3. tested on local jupyter notebook (import project worked)

Comment: What are you running when you say "run my code".

Comment: @BurhanKhalid it's about importing module. run my code means >> import project.module

Answer (score 0):

After Few days work around.. i found a solution.

> Add project root to pyhtonpath

from python shell

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/your/project/root")
```

it was not about _ _ init _ _.py or something else.